# Directed DFS in java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion, depth-first-search

I'm having problems with geting my DFS to work properly. 
The graph is conected like this:

```
0 --> 1
0 --> 5
5 --> 4
4 --> 3
4 --> 2
2 --> 3
2 --> 0
3 --> 2
3 --> 5
```

So the outcome after I run it through my DFS should be:

```
0,1,5,4,2,3
```

but I'm getting

```
0,1,5,2,3,4
```

heres the code:

```
package kth.id2010.lab.lab05;

public class DFS {

    static void dfs(int edges[][], int vertex, boolean[] visited){        
        visited[vertex] = true;
        for(int i = vertex + 1; i < edges[vertex].length; i++){
            if(edges[vertex][i] == 1 && !visited[i]){
                dfs(edges,i,visited);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int n = 6;
        int[][] edges = new int[n][n];
        boolean[] visited = new boolean[n];
        //Vertex nr: 0
        edges[0][0] = 0;
        edges[0][1] = 1; //0 --> 1
        edges[0][2] = 0;
        edges[0][3] = 0;
        edges[0][4] = 0;
        edges[0][5] = 1; //0 --> 5
        //Vertex nr: 1
        edges[1][0] = 0;
        edges[1][1] = 0;
        edges[1][2] = 0;
        edges[1][3] = 0;
        edges[1][4] = 0;
        edges[1][5] = 0;
        //Vertex nr: 2
        edges[2][0] = 1; //2 --> 0
        edges[2][1] = 0;
        edges[2][2] = 0;
        edges[2][3] = 1; //2 --> 3
        edges[2][4] = 0;
        edges[2][5] = 0;
        //Vertex nr: 3
        edges[3][0] = 0;
        edges[3][1] = 0;
        edges[3][2] = 1; //3 --> 2
        edges[3][3] = 0;
        edges[3][4] = 0;
        edges[3][5] = 1; //3 --> 5
        //Vertex nr: 4
        edges[4][0] = 0;
        edges[4][1] = 0;
        edges[4][2] = 1; //4 --> 2
        edges[4][3] = 1; //4 --> 3
        edges[4][4] = 0;
        edges[4][5] = 0;
        //Vertex nr: 5
        edges[5][0] = 0;
        edges[5][1] = 0;
        edges[5][2] = 0;
        edges[5][3] = 0;
        edges[5][4] = 1; //5 --> 4
        edges[5][5] = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            visited[i] = false;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i <n; i++){
            if(visited[i] == false){
                dfs(edges,i,visited);
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

I can't really figure out why it stops working after the 3 time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I noticed is that you start with i = vertex+i, therefore after you reached vertex 5 it will return to the main method where we entered from with vertex 0, and continue with vertex 2 and not vertex 4 as expected. So change the following line:

```
static void dfs(int edges[][], int vertex, boolean[] visited){        
    visited[vertex] = true;
    for(int i = vertex + 1; i < edges[vertex].length; i++){
        ...
```

to:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < edges[vertex].length; i++){
```

Comment: Actually he conceals his error by the last loop in the `main()`, which will start over for each vertex, thus all vertices get included.

Comment: But that is fine, we want to include all of them (e.g. if we have multiple not connected subgraphs)?! Just first the ones that are connected to each other :)

Comment: @Icewind I think, the last loop should be dropped in favor of a mere `dfs( edges, 0, visited )` call.

Comment: @Sirko yup that helped me with my next problem, if I hade vertecies that were not conected (e.g. if I added a 6 vertex that conects to 5 but not 5 to 6) it went trhough them aswell, wich it shouldnt